# What is the version of pip installed with python 3.9?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.9

Any version of Python >= 3.4 installed from the official python.org includes pip.

But I couldn't find what is the default version of pip that "comes" with python 3.9? and is there a difference if I install it on a system with an older python version, and an exiting pip?

I couldn't find an answer on google, and when I installed py3.9 on my pc, the pip3.9 is pip 9.0.1, which is the same as before, so I suspect if a pip3 version exists it does not update it.

Comment: The current bundled pip on the master branch of CPython is `21.0.1`. https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/ensurepip/_bundled .
According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html the latest stable version is always bundled.

Comment: Thank you!
I Assume this module only runs if there isn't an existing pip3 version installed on the system

Comment: It should install for each installation of python. A common problem new python programmers run into is using `pip install some_module` and installing a module under an unintended python installation.

Comment: If you want to know what version of `pip` came with your installation, run `from ensurepip import version; print(version())` with the installation of python you wish to check.

Answer (score 0):

As Axe319 commented:

According to docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html the latest stable version is always bundled (today it is 21.0.1)

Answer (score -1):

`pip3 -V` or `pip3 --version` will give you the answer

Comment: I installed python 3.9 on my system, after the installation the pip version is 9.0.1, which is the same version as before the installation. 
My question is how to find the version that will be installed with py3.9 on a fresh system